# Can I first rise my bread dough in the fridge?

Tags: bread, dough, yeast, fermentation, rising

So yesterday, after kneading the dough, I oiled a bowl and put the bread dough in, sealed the top with plastic wrap and put it right into the fridge. Now reading on the web, I found out that it might not be good to let the dough rise in the fridge as the cold has affect on the byproducts of the yeast.

The dough is only half rised after 24 hours in the fridge.. what should I do now? Try to get it rise more at room temperature or punch it down and let it rise again?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice BTW. This is a good question, so don't feel bad to see it closed as a duplicate. If you don't feel the linked duplicate answers your question, feel free to ask another one, but be specific about how that question differs.

Comment: Also by the way, the yeast by-products that come from slow rising of dough are highly sought after. Slow-risen bread is generally considered to be superior to fast-risen.

Comment: I do not see this as an exact duplicate,  this question is specifically about  "first rise". All though the info in the referenced question is sufficient to enlighten the OP.   The answer to this question is yes you can do the first rise in the fridge, there is no harm in doing your first rise in the fridge.